# overflow div hide than scrolling not come 

Tags: jquery, css

i have a div  with overflow auto and height fix ,
when i hide that div and show it again than scrolling not come but before hiding the div scrolling was there why this happen why style is changed to overflow hidden , and for solving this problem what should i do ?

Comment: Wow, three lines, one sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make it show again, set its overflow property to auto again.

Or just try jQuery's [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) & [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to see if that alone works out for you.